# cron not running bash commands

Tags: bash, cron

I am using the `whenever` [gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever) to generate cron commands.  I can check these commands with `crontab -l`. The generated commands are

```
24 15 * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /Users/Chris/Sites/covid_tracker && RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake countries:temp --silent >> log/cron.log 2>&1'

24 15 * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'echo '\''should see this in the log'\'' >> log/cron.log 2>&1'
```

The first command (bundle exec rake) runs and I can see the ouptut in the cron.log.  However, I see no output for the second command (echo) in the cron.log.

I want the echo command (and other bash commands I want to use) to run in the same directory as the `bundle exec rake` command, and the permissions to be same as if I had issue the command from that directory. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prefix the command with the same `cd /Users/Chris/Sites/covid_tracker &&` as the first command. This changes the working directory to that directory before running the command. Another option would be to create a shell script in that directory and run that. For example:

`24 15 * * * cd /Users/Chris/Sites/covid_tracker && ./runCron.sh >> log/cron.log 2>&1`

runCron.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash -l

cd /Users/Chris/Sites/covid_tracker
RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake countries:temp --silent
echo "should see this in the log"
```

(I'm not sure why you've specified a login shell with the -l param, is that needed for rake?)

Comment: Where do you think "log/cron.log" will end up?   Better specify the full path, cron has almost no environment.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille That's true, forgot that the cwd was specified in the script, not on the cron line. Will update!

Comment: All I needed to do was to specify the full path of the log file.  The ```-l``` is needed for rvm (ruby version manager) to  work.  Thank you.   For anyone looking for how to apply this specifically to the whenever gem, see this answer :https://stackoverflow.com/a/61845268/1299362.